# camera in android

Tags: android

how can i simulate camera of an android device?And what is the format of image obtained?
thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you mean in the emulator? I dont think its possible, I could be wrong though

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Emulator specification on the Android Website below, it seems like there is no support for camera/video capture (input).However as what systempuntoout have mentioned, you can use tomgibara solution to make it work on the emulator.

[Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html)